# jsf menuitem does not set property

Tags: jsf, properties, set, menuitem

i try to set normal property by menu-item, but it is does not work.

jsf:

```
<p:menuitem value="Names" 
            url="/master.xhtml"
        action="#{navigation.name}">

       <f:setPropertyActionListener target="navigation.name"
      value="Billy" />
</p:menuitem>
```

ManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="navigation") 
@SessionScoped //
public class LinksNavigation {

    public LinksNavigation() {
        super();
        this.milchFleisch = "./menuFleisch.xhtml";
    }

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

}
```

But it does not work. I dont set   with "f:setPropertyActionListener"
value = "Bully". How can i set property Value by menuItem??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `setPropertyActionListener`you have a `String` instead of an EL expression. Change

```
target="navigation.name"
```

to

```
target="#{navigation.name}"
```

Also, you need to take a closer look to at [the tag documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/menuitem.html) for `p:menuitem`. The attribute `action` is expecting a method expression. You will get a `MethodNotFoundException` with the way your code is set up. You need to change

```
action="#{navigation.name}"
```

to

```
action="#{navigation.getName}"
```

The abbreviated syntax `#{navigation.name}` is used for *value expressions*.

You are mixing navigation methods. You cannot have the attributes `url` and `action` together for the same `p:menuItem`. When I tested your code `action` and `setPropertyActionListener` were never called when `url` was present. This behavior suggest that you have to pick one or the other.

**COMMENT**

Based on your sample, I think you should rethink your approach. Let's pretend for a moment that you decided not to use `url="/master.xhtml"` and let's go over the sequence of events. After you press the menu item, the expression `#{navigation.name}` in `setPropertyActionListener` will first set the value "Billy" to your `name` property (e.g. `navigation.setName("Billy")`).  Then the expression `#{navigation.getName}` in the attribute `action` will call `getName()`. Now action will have the `String` value "Billy" and it will try to navigate to `Billy.xhtml` (assuming no navigation rules in `faces-config` and you have JSF 2.0). If that's the behavior you're after or if you have rules set up in `faces-config` and you are not hardcoding the value than that's another story entirely. Just keep this in mind.